# What does the electric field look like emanating from a tesla coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, experimental-physics, electric-fields

The magnetic field from a wire wraps around it. The direction depends on the direction of the current.  This means that the magnetic field passes through the center of the secondary coil, then out each end, and around the coil.

But a Tesla transmits a large electric field. If the electric field is orthogonal to the magnet field, does this mean that the electric field emanates directly out, perpendicular to the the length of the coil and that of the wire?

Comment: What do you mean by a "Tesla" here? Some sort of Tesla coil maybe?

Comment: Correct.  A Tesla coil

Comment: The magnetic field created in the coil induces via self-inductance the giant amount of charge separation and thus the electric field created in a tesla transformer (no electric field is transmitted).

Comment: I agree the there is an electric field between the primary and secondary coils. That is how the electron flow occurs on the secondary coil. But if you bring your hand close to the sphere at the top, you get an arc. This must be caused by a potential between your hand and the sphere. Shouldn't this imply a field emanating from the sphere perpendicular from the spheres surprise?

Comment: I think that the question should be edited to be more explicit. Your first sentence refers to a wire and then without any explanation, you talk about the field of two coils without any decription of geometry. You are asking the reader to guess your mind.